# Setting default value in ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, components

I have a component which renders "react-icons" object.
However, if no icon is supplied I want to display "NoIcon" string on the UI.

The **component A** is as such.

**component A**

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaHeart} from "react-icons/fa";

const Icon = ({FaIcon = "NoIcon"}) => {
  return (
    <div>
    <FaIcon/>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Icon;
```

and calling this component from another **components B** works :

**component B**

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from './components/icons/icon';
import { FaHeartBroken } from "react-icons/fa";

class App extends React.Component {  
    render(){
        return(
              <Icon FaIcon={ FaHeartBroken }/>
        )      
    }   
}
export default App;
```

this returns a "Broken Heart Icon" i.e .

But, if no icon is supplied in **component B** it should return a text i.e "NoIcon" in the UI.

**Component B**

```
....
....
      <Icon FaIcon/>
....
```

however this raises an error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: boolean.

Check the render method of `Icon`.
```

I also tried to set an `or` method on **component A** for value assignment, which did not work either.
Why providing no argument within `Icon` component, calling for a Boolean check?

**component A**

```
const Icon = ({FaIcon = FaHeart || "NoIcon"}) => {
    ....
```

Also tried these variations. These do not raise any error but do not return any value on the UI either.

**component B**

```
...
 <Icon/>
 <Icon FaIcon = "Test"/>
 <Icon FaIcon = {"Test"}/>
```

How do we resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A prop without a value `<Foo bar />` is actually shorthand for `<Foo bar={true} />`.

So this:

```
 <Icon FaIcon/>
```

Is not correct. And if you read that error again, it probably makes more sense now:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: boolean.

This means that it was expecting a a string/class/function, but got a boolean value instead. In this case `true` from the prop shorthand value.

This means that how you omit that prop, then you get the default.

```
 <Icon />
```

---

Secondly, this won't work:

```
const Icon = ({FaIcon = "NoIcon"}) => {
  return (
    <div>
    <FaIcon/>
    </div>
    );
};
```

To render something custom as `JSX` it must be a component. The import from `react-icons/fa` is a component, but the string `"NoIcon"` is not.

I think in this case it may be simpler to have a conditional that renders an icon if the prop is present, or a string if it is not.

Something like:

```
const Icon = ({FaIcon}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { FaIcon ? <FaIcon/> : "NoIcon" }
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

If you want one prop to handle an icon component or a string you could do this in a few ways. But if you want to be able to pass in icon component, or a string, then you do something like:

```
const Icon = ({FaIcon = "NoIcon"}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { typeof FaIcon === 'string' ? FaIcon : <FaIcon/>  }
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this case if the prop is a string (which applies to the default of `"NoIcon"` as well) then render it as a string. Otherwise assume it's a component and render it.

Comment: while this is correct, I'm pretty sure that after this fix the code will not "work fine as is". The default also needs to be a component - `NoIcon`, rather than a string `"NoIcon"`

Comment: Heh, yeah just noticed that myself :) Updated

Comment: Thanks @AlexWayne. 
Say in a situation I want to rather pass a custom text, e.g `<Icon FaIcon = "Test"/>` or 
`<Icon FaIcon = {"Test"}/>` how can I do that?
Please check the update example around the end of the question.

Comment: @everestial007 See my update at the end of my answer.